# How to set seed to compute_face_descriptor function in dlib?

Tags: python-3.x, artificial-intelligence, face-recognition, dlib

I am using **compute_face_descriptor** function in dlib which is the function of dlib.face_recognition_model_v1('dlib_face_recognition_resnet_model_v1.dat').

There is an option to set *"num_jitters"*. I set *"num_jitters"=10*, but the output embedding I am getting different on subsequent runs. I have tried setting seed using np.random.seed(43), but still, the output changes on subsequent runs

Is there a way to set seed in this function using "*num_jitters"=10* so that the output embedding doesn't change on subsequent runs?

Comment: Tried using random.seed(43) also, but no improvement. Still getting different embeddings on subsequent runs.

Answer (score 0):

"num_jitters". means how many times dlib will re-sample your face image each time **randomly** moving it a little bit. That's why you are getting different embeddings.